# Why is my page rendering when state has changed

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I need some help.
I am getting values from local storage and updating the state.
The state is getting updated but the output is not rendered. Here is my piece of code.

```
class register extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  email: "",
  select: "",
  password: "",
  checkbox: false,
  emailerror: "",
  erroroccured: 0,
  passworderror: "",
  remember: false,
  };
 }

componentDidMount() {
this.setState({ email: localStorage.getItem("pinemail") });

this.setState({ password: localStorage.getItem("pinpassword") });

  }
}
onChangeInput = (e) => {
 if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
  console.log("this");
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: !this.state.checkbox });
 } else {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 }
};

render() {
return (
<div>
 <Form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <FormInput
                      id="#email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      name="email"
                      onChange={this.onChangeInput}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>

                  <FormGroup>
                    <FormInput
                      type="password"
                      id="#password"
                      name="password"
                      onChange={this.onChangeInput}
                      placeholder="Password"
                    />

                  </FormGroup>
</div>
)}
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the state in your render function, you should set the value prop on your inputs

something like

```
          <FormGroup>
            <FormInput
              id="#email"
              placeholder="Email"
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.onChangeInput}
            />
          </FormGroup>

          <FormGroup>
            <FormInput
              type="password"
              id="#password"
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onChangeInput}
              placeholder="Password"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

User defined components must be capitalized: you need to rename your component to Register.
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized